# Query that show the value of two different columns php mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sum

i have two tables with fields and values:

TABLE respostas

```
Id      Corp_resp            Id_perg     Id_quest 
12       0,2                 1             1
13       0,5                 2             1
14       0,7                 3             1
15       0,2                 4             1
16       0,3                 5             1
17       0,6                 6             1
```

Table menu

```
Id_perg         percentagemadministrador Id_quest
1                             0.5        1    
2                             0.4        1         
3                             0.3        1          
4                             0,2        1
5                             0,1        1
6                             0,8        1
```

I want to associate the `id_quest` to `id_perg` and multiply the `corp_resp` with `percentagemadministrador` of the last 10 rows of the table `respostas`

`total=SUM(corp_resp*percentagemadministrador)` of the last 10 rows of the table.

```
<?php
mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("teste") or die(mysql_error()); // selecciona a database do server escolhido

//something like that

$query ="SELECT SUM(menu.percentagemadministrador*respostas.corp_resp) as TOTAL 
         FROM respostas 
         INNER JOIN menu 
         WHERE respostas.id_perg=menu.id_perg 
         AND respostas.id_quest=menu.id_perg 
         LIMIT id_perg=10";

$resultado = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

if($row = mysql_fetch_array($resultado)){

    echo " <center> Final: </center> ".$row['TOTAL'];
} ?>
```

Can you help with that?

Comment: I can't see 10 rows here

Comment: what do you mean for associate the id_quest to id_perg.. ? and how the two table are joined?(which key fields)

Comment: What have you do done so far to achieve the desired output?

Comment: Is a example Strawberry. Id_quest is 1 and inside you have have lots of questions and that are id_perg.

Comment: Please [stop using `mysql_*` functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php). [These extensions](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.removed-exts-sapis.php) have been removed in PHP 7. Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) statements for [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) and [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and consider using PDO, [it's really pretty easy](http://jayblanchard.net/demystifying_php_pdo.html).

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use a subselect for getting the 10 firts id only

```
SELECT SUM(menu.percentagemadministrador*respostas.corp_resp) as TOTAL 
FROM respostas INNER JOIN menu 
WHERE respostas.id_perg=menu.id_perg 
AND respostas.id_quest=menu.id_perg 
AND id_perg in (select id_perg from respostas order by id_perg limit 10);
```

if don't work in we can try with inner join

```
SELECT SUM(menu.percentagemadministrador*respostas.corp_resp) as TOTAL 
FROM respostas 
INNER JOIN menu on ( respostas.id_perg=menu.id_perg 
     AND respostas.id_quest=menu.id_perg)  
INNER JOIN  ( select id_perg from  respostas order by id_perg limit 10) as t2 
 on (respostas.id = t2. id)
```

Comment: That don´t works, tell don´t support "This version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery'"

Comment: which version of mysql you are using?

Comment: PHP/5.6.12 is the version

Comment: i trying like that but is giving all the time the same value. "SELECT SUM(menu.percentagemadministrador*respostas.corp_resp) as TOTAL FROM respostas INNER JOIN menu ORDER BY id_resp DESC LIMIT 5";

Comment: Please, based on the value in your question, update your question and show me the result you need obtain..

Comment: I update the tables for you see the values i want to give.   total=sum(corp_resp*percentagemadministrador)

Total=(o,2*0,2+0,3*0,1+0,6*0,8)=0,55

Print in screen total=0,55

Comment: The value is from the last 3 rows in both tables one example.

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'respostas order by id_perg limit 10) as t2 on (respostas.id = t2. id)' at line 2         That is the output.